# Unexpected end of input Error in a simple code

Tags: javascript

I was doing an exercise in Javascript, using the Google Chrome Console. So I've got an exception and I can't see anything wrong with the code:

```
var array1 = [1,2,3]
var l

for (l = 0; l < array1.length-1; l++)
{

        if (array1[l] == 1)
        {

            alert("what?")

        { 

}
```

It returns me this exception:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Am I missing something?

Comment: if statement has wrong bracket

Comment: When I rewrote it was working, but I just couldn't see where the mistake was.

Comment: after alert('what?") there should be } not {

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your if statement isn't closed well.
Try this:

```
 var array1 = [1,2,3]
 var l

 for (l = 0; l < (array1.length-1); l++) {
   if (array1[l] == 1) {
     alert("what?")
  } 
 }
```

You had this

```
if( ... ) { {
```

Should be

```
if( ... ) { }
```

Answer (score 1):

## Don't forget to add semi-colons `;`.

also change the `{` to `}` in closing of `if`

```js
var array1 = [1,2,3];
var l;

for (l = 0; l < array1.length-1; l++)
{

        if (array1[l] == 1)
        {

            alert("what?");

        }

}
```

Comment: This does not only answer the question but also reminds about the semicolons, which in this case were not the problem but in the future might as well be, NotCreativeBoy take this advice.

Comment: sorry TheRickest, i was just editing somehow i copied the wrong name i intended to adres the original poster my apologies

Answer (score 0):

the code like this may be better:

```
var array1 = [1,2,3];
for (var l = 0, n = array1.length; l < n; l ++) {
    if (array1[l] == 1) {
        alert("what?");
    }
}
```